# Need to make my Dates in the 2000s and create "June-2000" in R

Tags: r, date, character, as.date

1. The First Problem

I had Dates that looked like this but were factors

**$ SampleDate : Factor w/ 16 levels "","10/4/02","6/10/02",**

So I used this to make them dates

`CB6.1$Date <- as.Date(CB6.1$SampleDate, "%m/%d/%Y")`

But my Years are all 0

**$ Date  : Date, format: "0000-06-13" "0000-06-13" "0000-06-13"**

I would like my years to start with 2 --> "2000-06-13"

2. The Second Problem

I use this to isolate the year and month only

`CB6.1$Month_Year <- substr(CB6.1$Date, 1,7)`

**$ Month_Year : chr  "0000-06" "0000-06" "0000-06" "0000-06"**

It then becomes a character, which I don't mind, but I want to

change the format to "June-2000"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change `"%m/%d/%Y"` to `"%m/%d/%y"`

Comment: Try: `format(x, "%B-%Y")`